# Have Subversion (in Eclipse) Ignore Specific File

Tags: eclipse, svn

Is there any way to have Subversion (in Eclipse) ignore a specific file.  I've tried going to Team --> Synchronize with Repository, and the Mark as Merged option isn't available.  I don't think it's possible, but does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about eclipse and what ignoring file has to do with marking as merged, but what I'd do is `svn pe svn:ignore <path>` and add the file there.

Comment: I just want the arrow to go away.  I have a file that has to point at local builds instead of release builds for development, so all of my projects are marked as out of sync, which makes life a little harder :)

Comment: So I was right (for what I can tell by your accepting the answer:)).

Answer (score 0):

After having refreshed your project with the repo, you just have to right click your file and "add to svn ignore" in the Team menu.

The option is available only if your file is not already in the repo.

If your file already exists in the repo, you will have to delete it first and recreate it as if it is a new one.

You can ignore only a single file or setup a mask.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me as if the file is already added, which is a state it can't be ignored from. You need to remove it first, and you need to synchronise it fully first such that the server and client views of the file are equal.

You can do this by reverting the file, but keep a local copy so you can fix the file after it has been deleted from both sides (you'll delete the client copy, and will have to put it back again). After that, delete the file from the client side, commit, synchronise, put the file back, and then mark it as ignored from the SVN team menu (do not 'add' the file).